# JavaMail: How to send a variable value as email content instead of just text?

Tags: java, variables, jakarta-mail

I have the cut following code below, for emailing something to me.

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("emailfrom@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("emailto@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Email title");
        message.setText("Email body");
        Transport.send(message);
```

It works fine when i put the message.setText line to something in quotations "", eg.
    message.setText("Hello there");

But the setText part is underlined in red whenever I try to use a variable name, eg.

```
String x = Hello;
String y = there;
```

and use the above code with the line:

```
 message.setText(x + y);
```

With the desired message to say "Hello there", using the variables instead of the quoted text.

How do i do this?

Comment: What Exception you are getting? Did you try running this in Eclipse or in Windows CMD?

Comment: Are Hello and there variables or message to email to emailto@gmail.com?

Answer (score 3):

`setText` should accept any `String` instance. It's possible you were getting an error because you didn't add quotes around "Hello" and "there";

```
String x = "Hello";
String y = "there";
message.setText(x + " " + y);
```

Comment: Got it, cheers. Its always the smallest stupidest and most basic things!